# Save blank file in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, cocoa, zerofill

I am working on a code that, among other things, must save a zero-filled file. It can expect to create a file from 10MB to even 1GB blank.

It must be similar to this Unix command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=my_image.dsk count=20480
```

I could do this one work with small sizes:

```
int totalSize = 1024*1024;
char buf[totalSize];
strcpy(buf,"");

NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithBytes:buf length:sizeof(buf)];

//NSLog(@"%@", theData);
NSLog(@"%lu", sizeof(buf));

[theData writeToFile:@"/Users/foo/Desktop/my_image.dsk" atomically:YES];
```

But if I try a bigger value (1024*1024*10, for instance), it crashes.
So I tried:

```
NSFileManager *ddd = [[NSFileManager alloc ] init];
[ddd createFileAtPath:@"/Users/foo/Desktop/my_image.dsk" contents:[NSData data] attributes:nil];
```

It creates an empty file, but is not good because the file size is zero. It should not be zero.

I spent hours trying to find an answer without success. I want to do this in Obj-C, but C is also an option before I go nuts.

Please, someone give-me some light!

Thanks in advance!

-- Edit --

Thanks everyone, but one more thing: is it possible to write without allocating everything on memory?

Comment: It crashes because you are allocating it on the stack. You have a limited amout of memory on the stack. You are trying to allocate 1 MB on the stack as it is, you are better using a malloc & memset call.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: You should not `malloc` & `memset` in general, use `calloc` instead.  You can save a lot of memory that way.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Really? I've heard the other way around, and that memset is better than a calloc call, because it is inlined more? Just what I've heard, can't tell ya either way.

Comment: Also note that `-dataWithBytes:length:` copies the data sent to it, you would be better off using `-dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:` instead.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: How's that? I thought calloc just did the multiplication for you and bzeroed the allocated memory.

Comment: @Chuck: It has the option of doing that, but it can also give you pre-zeroed memory or give you copy-on-write zeroed pages from the OS.  For large allocations (1 MiB or larger), modern Unix-like systems almost invariable use copy-on-write so the allocation uses no memory except a little bit of overhead.  You can test it, write a program that allocates 2x total RAM with `calloc`, compare it to a program that uses `malloc`/`memset`.  The difference is ENORMOUS.  (The `bzero` function is almost universally implemented as a call to `memset` these days.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dd`.  This will let you write, e.g., 10 GB without worrying about memory or address space.

```
NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
long size = ...; // Note! dd multiplies this by 512 by default
NSString *path = ...;
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/dd"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"dd", @"if=/dev/zero",
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"of=%s", [path fileSystemRepresentation]],
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"count=%ld", size],
    nil]];
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
if ([task terminationStatus] != 0) {
    // an error occurred...
}
[task release];
```

An advantage is that sophisticated users can kill `dd` if something goes wrong.

**About sandboxing:** My suspicion is that this will work fine even in a sandbox, but I'd be curious to know for sure.  According to documentation ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxDesignGuide.pdf)), a subprocess "simply inherits the sandbox of the process that created it."  This is exactly how you'd expect it to work on Unix.

You can be sure that `dd` will stick around since Apple claims that OS X conforms to SUSv3.

Comment: Interesting.. do you think it would be too much work implement a "kill" action on error by default?

Comment: Got an error: `Program received signal: "SIGABRT"` and in the log: `2012-01-16 01:56:05.977 File handler[2448:903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'launch path not accessible'
*** Call stack at first throw:`

Comment: @GiancarloMariot: As written, errors are detected when `dd` exits, so there is no need to kill `dd`.  The `dd` program will normally exit immediately upon encountering an error.

Comment: @GiancarloMariot: Looks like you need to add `setLaunchPath:`.  I've changed the code above.

Comment: Thanks Dietrich.. Best option so far. I'll check all again in the morning (2am, GMT 0 here)..

Comment: Definitely nice, but it does code in requirements that `dd` exist, is runnable by the current user and process (OS X does have sandbox environments available that can prevent it), and that it exist at `/bin/dd`. But ten points for making something really easy. :)

Comment: @sarnold: `dd` is guaranteed to exist according to Mac OS X documentation, which states that Mac OS X conforms to SUS3.  (The code also assumes that the `NSTask` class exists, that `/dev/zero` and `Foundation.framework` exist, and other such things.)  There exists no user unable to run `dd` nor is such a situation forseeable.  I don't know how sandbox entitlements get inherited by `NSTask` objects, so that is the only real issue.

Comment: Note that you can tell which programs are executable by arbitrary users by looking at their paths: everything in `/bin` is runnable by everyone, programs in `/sbin` often require privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the sandboxing guide, that's superb. The last time I tried to find out more information about it, I found it remarkably underdocumented.

Answer (score 4):

This is relatively simple in the POSIX API:

```
int f = open("filename", O_CREAT|O_EXCL, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
if (f < 0) {
    perror("open filename");
    exit(1);
}

char empty = 0;

pwrite(f, &empty, sizeof(char), <offset into the file>);
```

The offset is specified using an integer of type `off_t`, which might not be large enough for your specific needs. Check your system API documentation to discover the 64-bit file interfaces if it isn't large enough.

The best part of this approach is that it only takes a few bytes of program memory -- you're not allocating 10 gigabytes of nothing to write your file.

Another even simpler approach is to use the `truncate(2)` system call. Not all platforms support extending the file with `truncate(2)`, but for the ones that do, it's *one call*.

Comment: Note that not all applications want to create sparse files.  Might want to change permissions to 0666 and let the user set their own `umask`.

Comment: Great, I was looking for something that does not allocate everything on memory, so this is a good start. But you lost me with this offset.. xD

Comment: Extending the file with `truncate(2)` appears to be required by POSIX.

Comment: @Huw: Nice; some day the older systems that didn't support some of POSIX's nicer features will be odd or obscure enough that we'll be able to clean up a lot of code like this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
int totalSize = 1024*1024;
// don't allocate on the stack
char *buf = calloc(totalSize, sizeof(char));

NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buf length:totalSize];

//NSLog(@"%@", theData);
NSLog(@"%lu", totalSize);

[theData writeToFile:@"/Users/foo/Desktop/my_image.dsk" atomically:YES];
```

You could also try this, less of a memory hog, and it works with a 1 GB file.

```
void writeBlankBytes(FILE *file, size_t numKB)
{
    static char *oneKBZero = NULL;

    if (oneKBZero == NULL)
    {
        oneKBZero = calloc(1024, sizeof(char));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numKB; i++) {
        fwrite(oneKBZero, 1, 1024, file);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens to this approach as `totalSize` approaches 10GB?

Comment: Well then you are screwed, unless for some ungodly reason you have more than 10 GBs of RAM.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: If you used `calloc` instead of `malloc`/`memset` (which you always *should*), you could be fine on 64-bit computers even if they don't have much RAM.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: `sizeof(buf)` is the same as `sizeof(char *)`, which is 4 or 8 on most systems.  You probably mean `totalSize`.  Note that `sizeof(char) == 1` is explicitly guaranteed by the C standard, so it can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. I came to a solution. This is basically a sketch of the code that I am about to put in a cocoa app.

Works fine and I think I only need some precautions with the size variable and it will be enough.

```
long size = 2000*500;

NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"/Users/foo/Desktop/testeFile.dsk"];

NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/dd"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    @"if=/dev/zero",
                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"of=%s", [path fileSystemRepresentation]],
                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"count=%ld", size],
                    nil]];
NSLog(@"%@",[task arguments]);
[task launch];

//[task waitUntilExit]; //The app would stuck here.. better use the loop

int cont = 0;
while ([task isRunning]) {
    cont++;
    if(cont%100==0) NSLog(@". %d", cont);
}

if ([task terminationStatus] != 0) {
    NSLog(@"an error occurred...");
}
[task release];
[path release];

NSLog(@"Done!");
```

Comment: Do note that this places a dependence upon `dd` being available and specifically located in `/bin/dd` -- if either requirement is not met your program will fail. While this will probably work for you for years, I think simpler methods are available that won't have these dependencies.

Comment: @sarnold I wish I could find a good method as you say, but all of them throw the file to the memory before saving and if a user asks for a 1GB file, it will probably crash the application or at least become an elephant.
I've been looking everywhere for a simple solution, then I got here and all the solutions I found are these you can see here.. =(
If you have a new suggestion, it would be great! =)

Comment: [Dietrich's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8874811/377270) is good; the chances of running into the `NPROC` `setrlimit(2)` constraint against starting new processes is pretty low and the link to the sandboxing guide he provided indicates to me that you, as the application author, rather than the _user_, is responsible for providing the sandbox, so that's not likely to be a real impediment to your application. My suggestion _does_ create a sparse file (which may not be what you want) and it requires working at a different API level.